# Exportar un archivo excel con varias paginas a archivo .CSV

Tags: c#, excel, csv, xls

Estoy intentando convertir un archivo `Excel` `(.xls)` a un `(.csv)` pero no consigo hacerlo bien, el código que muestro a continuación esta sacado tal cual de un ejemplo, para ello, me apoyo en la librería [Aspose.Cells](https://products.aspose.com/cells/net) y el resultado no es optimo, el código lee el archivo `.xls`, determina la cantidad de hojas que tiene y después en el bulce `FOR` se supone que va copiando los datos de cada hoja (en cada iteracion) para al final generar el `.csv` pero lo que finalmente ocurre es que solo accede a la primera hoja con lo cual, si el archivo tiene 10 hojas obtengo un `.csv` con los datos de la primera hoja pero repetidos 10 veces...

Segun mi teoria, en la linea `workbook.Worksheets.ActiveSheetIndex = idx;` se especifica la hoja con la cual trabajas pero siempre obtiene la primera, o eso creo... ¿Alguien tiene una idea de que puede estar pasando?
No obstante... podria utilizar cualquier otra .dll si alguno conoce alguna relativamente ligera, el problema por lo que intento hacer esto es porque trabajo con un archivo Excel muy grande (15 hojas * 25000 lineas) y si lo convierto a .csv es mucho mas liviano al trabajar con el.

```
        string filePath = @"C:\Users\pepito\Desktop\2019.xls";

        //Load your source workbook
        Workbook workbook = new Workbook(filePath);

        //0-byte array
        byte[] workbookData = new byte[0];

        //Text save options. You can use any type of separator
        TxtSaveOptions opts = new TxtSaveOptions();
        opts.Separator = '\t';

        //Copy each worksheet data in text format inside workbook data array
        for (int idx = 0; idx < workbook.Worksheets.Count; idx++)
        {
            //Save the active worksheet into text format
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            workbook.Worksheets.ActiveSheetIndex = idx;
            int a = workbook.Worksheets.ActiveSheetIndex;
            workbook.Save(ms, opts);

            //Save the worksheet data into sheet data array
            ms.Position = 0;
            byte[] sheetData = ms.ToArray();

            //Combine this worksheet data into workbook data array
            byte[] combinedArray = new byte[workbookData.Length + sheetData.Length];
            Array.Copy(workbookData, 0, combinedArray, 0, workbookData.Length);
            Array.Copy(sheetData, 0, combinedArray, workbookData.Length, sheetData.Length);

            workbookData = combinedArray;
        }

        //Save entire workbook data into file
        File.WriteAllBytes(filePath + ".out.csv", workbookData);
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: Desconozco Aspose.Cells. Creo que la librería más utilizada es [EPPLUS](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus).
En [este enlace](https://riptutorial.com/epplus) tienes ejemplos de como manejarla.

Comment: @Roger Torné y es posible convertir a .csv? No logro verlo... ¿Conoces la libreria?  Gracias!

Comment: Te respondo más extensamente en una "Respuesta"

Answer (score 1):

La librería EPPlus está especializada en leer/escribir archivos de Excel. Es bastante eficiente en esta tarea pero no guarda la información en formato csv. Mi solución sería utilizar EPPlus para iterar en cada hoja de Escel que contenga el archivo, leer su contenido, parsarlo a un array y escribir una función que lo envíe a un csv (código obtenido [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8666518/how-can-i-write-a-general-array-to-csv-file)).

Te dejo una solución parcial, si exploras otros ejemplos verás que hay más posibilidades, algunas más eficientes, en ocasiones depende del formato del excel (si tiene tablas definidas por ejemplo). Lo escribo al vuelo, aunque he copiado y pegado una parte.

Iterar por las hojas de Excel de un archivo

```
var package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo("ejemplo.xlsx"));
foreach (var workSheet in excel.Workbook.Worksheets)
{
  var start = workSheet.Dimension.Start;
  var end = workSheet.Dimension.End;
  for (int row = start.Row; row <= end.Row; row++)
  { // Fila a fila ..
      for (int col = start.Column; col <= end.Column; col++)
      { // ... Celda a celda...
          object cellValue = workSheet.Cells[row, col].Text; // Valor de la celda actual. Guardar en un Array[]
      }
  }
}
```

Guardar el array:

```
public static void SaveArrayAsCSV(Array arrayToSave, string fileName)
{
    using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(fileName))
    {
        WriteItemsToFile(arrayToSave, file);
    }
}

private static void WriteItemsToFile(Array items, TextWriter file)
{
    foreach (object item in items)
    {
        if (item is Array)
        {
            WriteItemsToFile(item as Array, file);
            file.Write(Environment.NewLine);
        }
        else file.Write(item + ",");   
    }
}
```